# O que são os cores e routers em vários frameworks PHP

Tags: php, framework

Sempre utilizei PHP sem framework. Eu utilizo no padrão MVC, mas eu apenas criava uma pasta pro view, uma pro controller e uma pro model, mas recentemente resolvi estudar um framework e ele utiliza um tal de core e routers. Fiz perguntas ao professor mas ele não me respondeu (o curso é online). Tem um outro curso de PHP que adquiri recentemente, a ideia dele é usar PHP "puro" para criarmos nosso próprio framework, mas novamente o curso ia bem até chegar na parte de core e router

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Core

é onde toda a lógica e o "coração" do framework ficam, nesta pasta encontram-se todas as configurações necessárias para que o framework funcione. **Nunca mexa nesta pasta a não ser que você saiba o que esta fazendo**.

#### Router

Router significa **roteador** ou **rotas**
e é a pasta onde ficam os "caminhos" da sua aplicação, nela você define qual URL sera utilizada no seu projeto, por exemplo;

```
localhost:8080/rota1/subrota
```

`rota1`e `subrota` serão definidas no arquivo/pasta de `router` e elas levaram para um código especifico que você definir.

Comment: Posso estar falando besteira, mas no caso do Core, não seria a mesma coisa de simplesmente criar um arquivo chamado Config? e no caso do Router, não é a mesma coisa de autoload?

Comment: basicamente sim mas os framework possuem muitos recursos já embutidos para que voce nao precise se preocupar com configuracao pesada por exemplo enviar emails, salvar arquivos na nuvem e etc.
o router segue o mesmo principio, nele voce ja vai ter configuracoes prontas para login, logout e etc.
quando voce comecar a estudar PHP puro e criar seu proprio framework como disse voce vai conseguir entender melhor mas por enquanto bons estudos! :)